# Commutator of $[\hat{x}, \hat{k}]$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, fourier-transform, commutator

We define the operators $$\hat{x} |x\rangle = x |x\rangle\tag{1}$$ and $$\hat{k} |k\rangle = k |k\rangle\tag{2}$$ where $$\sqrt{2\pi} \Psi(k)=\int dxe^{-ikx}\Psi(x)\tag{3}$$ and $$\langle x|k\rangle = e^{ikx}/\sqrt{2\pi}.\tag{4}$$
How to calculate the commutator $$[\hat x,\hat k]~?\tag{5}$$

---

What I noticed:
$$\partial _x \langle x | k\rangle = ik \langle x | k  \rangle$$
$$\partial _k \langle x | k\rangle = ix \langle x | k  \rangle$$
I attempted to calculate $\hat x \hat k |\Psi\rangle$; however, I don't seem to get anywhere:

$$\hat x \hat k |\Psi\rangle = \hat x \hat k \int dk |k\rangle \langle k| \int dx |x\rangle \langle x | \Psi \rangle \\ = -i \int dk k |k \rangle \partial _k \langle k | \Psi \rangle$$

I would appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward approach would be to calculate the matrix element of $\hat{x}\hat{k}-\hat{k}\hat{x}$, e.g.,
$$
\langle x'|\hat{x}\hat{k}-\hat{k}\hat{x}|x''\rangle =
\int dx \Psi_{x'}(x)(\hat{x}\hat{k}-\hat{k}\hat{x})\Psi_{x''}(x)
$$
One needs some care with where $x$ designates an integration variable, a quantum number and an operator, but otherwise it is just about doing math with Fourier transform. Note that the problem is of homework level, which is why I do not go in more details.

Answer (score 0):

Start by using your FT definitions to show that
$$
\langle x|\hat k|\psi\rangle = -i  \partial_x \langle x|\psi\rangle.
$$